# Assigning "Enumerate-Resume" to a keyboard shortcut

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Has anyone figured out a way to assign "Enumerate-Resume" a keyboard shortcut? I'd love not to reach for a mouse every time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems to be related to an editor at first glance. Which one are you using?

Comment: Apologies. I should have stipulated that I am working in Lyx with the enumitem module in the memoir document class.